# Python Scraping JavaScript using Selenium and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a JavaScript enables page using BS and Selenium. 
I have the following code so far. It still doesn't somehow detect the JavaScript (and returns a null value). In this case I'm trying to scrape the Facebook comments in the bottom. (Inspect element shows the class as postText)
Thanks for the help!

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get('http://techcrunch.com/2012/05/15/facebook-lightbox/')  
html_source = browser.page_source  
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html_source)  
comments = soup("div", {"class":"postText"})  
print comments
```

Comment: You may want to try setting a wait on the page - you are likely exiting before the page has time to fully load (remember, it is just like a browser and experiences latency). In your case, you could likely solve it by just waiting for a certain period of time, but the more elegant solution(s) can be found at http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits

Comment: I'm not too sure if the wait was the issue, as I removed browser.quit() and ran the program. There was no luck.

Comment: The problem is actually the line before - it is loading `page_source` before there is any source to be loaded :)

Answer (score 10):

There are some mistakes in your code that are fixed below. However, the class "postText" must exist elsewhere, since it is not defined in the original source code.
My revised version of your code was tested and is working on multiple websites.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get('http://techcrunch.com/2012/05/15/facebook-lightbox/')  
html_source = browser.page_source  
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source,'html.parser')  
#class "postText" is not defined in the source code
comments = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'postText'})  
print comments
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It really helped me save a lot of time.