# Scraping asp and java script generated table with python 2.7, beautiful soup and selenium

Tags: javascript, asp.net, python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape a JavaScript generated table and write some of the data to a csv file. I am restricted to python 2.7, Beautiful Soup and/or Selenium. The closest code that will do part of what I need is in question [14529849](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529849/python-scraping-javascript-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup), but all I am getting in return is an empty list.
The site I an looking at is:

http://hydromet.lcra.org/repframe.html

with the source:
http://hydromet.lcra.org/repstage.asp

For example, one of the records looks like this:

```
 <tr>
 <td class="flagmay"><a href="javascript:dataWin('STAGE','119901','Colorado River at Winchell')" class="tablink">Colorado River at Winchell</a></td>
<td align="left" class="flagmay">Jan 12 2016  5:55PM</td><td align="right" class="flagmay">2.48</td><td align="right" class="flagmay">4.7</td></tr>
```

and what I am trying to write to csv, should look like:

Station|                   StationID|    Time |               Stage|    Flow

Colorado River at Winchell | 119901 |      Jan 12 2016  5:55PM | 2.48 |   4.7

Can anyone please give me any pointers?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what's the point of selenium in this whole story if you are not planning to test the UI. Why not use `urllib` or [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) to get the page, and then BeautifulSoup to parse it? And how does your `soup` call look like?

Comment: `url = ("http://hydromet.lcra.org/repframe.html")
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
soup.prettify()
table1 = soup.find("table", class_="tablink")`
The csv file is empty and I have no idea how to get the station id which is coming form this portion of the html:
href="javascript:dataWin('STAGE','_119901_','Colorado River at Winchell')

Comment: shouldn't url be `url = ("http://hydromet.lcra.org/repstage.asp")`?

Comment: I have to preface with the fact that this is my second attempt to scraping, so thank you for your patience. If I change the url, I get **IndexError: list index out of range**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Im using `pandas`, `requests` and `BeautifulSoup4` libraries and tested that the code works with python `2.7.11` and `3.5.1`

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://hydromet.lcra.org/repstage.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table')

# convert the html table data into pandas data frames, skip the heading so that it is easier to add a column
df = pandas.read_html(str(tables[1]), skiprows={0}, flavor="bs4")[0]

# loop over the table to find out station id and store it in a dict obj
a_links = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'tablink'})
stnid_dict = {}
for a_link in a_links:
    cid = ((a_link['href'].split("dataWin('STAGE','"))[1].split("','")[0])
    stnid_dict[a_link.text] = cid

# add the station id column from the stnid_dict object above
df.loc[:, (len(df.columns)+1)] = df.loc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: stnid_dict[x])
df.columns = ['Station', 'Time', 'Stage', 'Flow', 'StationID']

# added custom order of columns to add in csv, and to skip row numbers in the output file
df.to_csv('station.csv', columns=['Station', 'StationID', 'Time', 'Stage', 'Flow'], index=False)
```

This script will create a CSV file called `station.csv` at the same location as the script.

Comment: Alan, thank you very much. If I get permissions to install pandas I will be able to test it.