# BeautifulSoup Returning empty array

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to scrape data off a website, but using the code beneath it would return an empty array " [] " for some reason. I can't seem to figure out the reasoning behind it. When I check the html generated there seems to be a lot of \t \r \n. I am unsure what the issue seems to be with my code.

```
url = "http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/price_movement_result.htm?location=priceMoveSearch&PageNo=1&SearchMethod=2&mkt=hk&LangCode=en&StockType=ALL&Ranking=ByMC&x=51&y=6"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
print rows
```

I have attempted to parse non ".text" and also "lxml" instead of "html.parser" but ended up with the same result.

EDIT: Found the workaround, used selenium to open the page and grab the source that way instead.

```
url = "http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/price_movement_result.htm?location=priceMoveSearch&PageNo=1&SearchMethod=2&mkt=hk&LangCode=en&StockType=ALL&Ranking=ByMC&x=51&y=6"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
f = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this page use javascript to fetch data from server, and you can find javascript use this link to request data in chrome's dev_tools, so you can requests this link to get the info you need.

```
http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/ws/Result.asmx/GetData?location=priceMoveSearch&SearchMethod=2&LangCode=en&StockCode=&StockName=&Ranking=ByMC&StockType=ALL&mkt=hk&PageNo=1&ATypeSHEx=&AType=&FDD=&FMM=&FYYYY=&TDD=&TMM=&TYYYY=
```

there is no need to use selenium

Answer (score 0):

There are no true HTML rows in the document. The rows are dynamically generated by JavaScript. BeautifulSoup cannot execute JavaScript.

Comment: If i were to use selenium driver would I be able to scrape the site? If not what would be the best possible solution. EDIT : just tried it it works thanks

Comment: According to this discussion, yes you can. Never tried it myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529849/python-scraping-javascript-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 0):

If you view the contents of the html.text variable, you will notice that the content is generated dynamically and does not have any valid  elements.