# Web-scraping a javascript table with python BueatifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I can't get one javascript table with BueatifulSoup, returning empty array

I tried to get data from this page.
https://www.hkex.com.hk/Mutual-Market/Stock-Connect/Statistics/Historical-Daily?sc_lang=en#select4=1&select5=2&select3=0&select2=3&select1=24

```
import requests, json
text = requests.get("https://www.hkex.com.hk/Mutual-Market/Stock-Connect/Statistics/Historical-Daily?sc_lang=en#select4=0&select5=2&select3=0&select2=3&select1=24")
data = json.loads(text)

print(data['Scty'])
```

Comment: Do you mean bueatifulsoup?

Comment: the webpage you are downloading contains html not json, so Python throws a error. Also where is your code using Bueatiful Soup?

Comment: I started with BeutifulSoap, but didnt work. So I tried with Json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054232/beautifulsoup-returning-empty-array?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: which table on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another url you can use - found by looking at the network tab. A little string manipulation on the response text and you have a string that can be loaded with `json` and contains everything on the page (including for all 4 drop down geographies). There is no need for bs4. You can extract everything you want with `json` library.

Explore it [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=5e7e19a4b7d444a28ca8d41d45aac1d6).

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/DailyStat/data_tab_daily_20190425e.js?_=1556252093686')
data = json.loads(r.text.replace('tabData = ',''))
```

For example, path to first row of table on landing page:

[image]