# HTML does not reflect webpage content in browser for Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape content from a website using Beautiful Soup. When doing some testing, I get the following output (this is just the last bit at the end):

```
<!-- 6. Load the app --> 
 <my-app>
    Loading...
 </my-app>

</body>

</html>
```

The "Loading" part is what I want. Why is the html not loading for this? The same thing happens if I view source in Google. How can I scrape if I cannot see the code.

The page in question is:

https://searchusan.ama-assn.org/finder/usan/search/*/relevant/1

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beautiful Soup loads the page that it sees when the page first renders.  Unfortunately the page you are trying to scrape uses javascript which renders the information you want after the initial page load.  Javascript always creates problems for Beautiful Soup and the only pure Beautiful Soup solution I got to work with javascript was frightfully hairy, slow, and crash/hang prone.

I recommend you use a tool like Selenium with Beautiful Soup which will allow the entire page to load.

Here is an example: [Python Scraping JavaScript using Selenium and Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529849/python-scraping-javascript-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup)

Comment: Thank  you for the reply. I will try it. I see the info I want if I got the inspector-elements in google. Is there a way to get at the data from there?

Comment: No, the reason you see the info is that the javascript has loaded by the time you looked at it in the inspector.  The only way you could get it from there is to wait till it loads and then manually save the webpage to your file system and scrape that.  But that isn't an automated solution.

Comment: One follow-up...Why is it, even after the page loads and displays, the source code still shows 'loading'?