# Beautiful Soup not loading the entire page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a web crawling script

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import bs4
res = requests.get('https://in.linkedin.com/in/ASAMPLEUSERNAME', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'})

print(res.text)
```

> please replace 'ASAMPLEUSERNAME' in the url in the code with some dummy linkedin user

But the code only gives me partial incomplete (almost nothing) webpage source

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML does not reflect webpage content in browser for Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495589/html-does-not-reflect-webpage-content-in-browser-for-beautiful-soup)

Comment: The content on the page may be generated by client-side JavaScript, which is why the `requests` library cannot access it. This has been answered on SO before, and the solution is usually to use Selenium to get the page, wait for the JS to load, and strip the page source from that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as BenG says, the content is dynamic. You can see that by having a look at the source code. A lot of the html there includes "script". You can use another library such as selenium to load the dynamic elements.

EDIT: this is how you would get the source code of the page using selenium in theory. In practice, it seems to be a bit more difficult. I get redirected to the login of Linkedin. But you can extend the code to log in and then get the source code of the page. Should you need help, let me know. Note that for this code to work you need to have chrome installed and a chromedriver located at the path that says yourdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=yourdriver)
url ='https://in.linkedin.com/in/SOMEUSER'
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you do not use BeautifulSoup. I guess you need something like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)
driver.get(url)
page = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(page), 'html.parser')
```

Comment: What does the `return document.body.innerHTML` stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have suggested Selenium, which works fine for most web scraping business.

If you're concerned about speed, though, go to the javascript sources and look for where the actual content you are interested in comes from, probably through ajax requests. Maybe you can access the API endpoints directly.