# I'm missing html information when i requests for a page to extract a specific class

Tags: python, html, python-requests-html

```
import requests
import bs4

llista = ['https://www.flashscore.com/match/rHNd9uXG/#match-summary/lineups','https://www.flashscore.com/match/pW4gALHA/#match-summary/lineups']


for i in range(len(llista)): #Local
    base_url = llista[i]
    res = requests.get(base_url)
    locals()["lsoup" + str(i+1)] = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

lsoup1.select(".If__playerNameInner")
```

I'm missing information in this part, i receiver just this class:

```
[<div class="container__detailInner" id="detail">
 <div class="critical__wrapper">
 <div class="critical__wrapper__logo logo--mobile flashscore-com-white"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="critical__tournament"><div> </div></div>
 </div>]
```

i request to the url the HTML code to extract the class If__playerNameInner that containt the name of the players in the field, so when i review the code in the page, its a different code that i received in the requests on Python, thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but will say modifying [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) is bad.  Read the note in the link.  If you are numbering variables, you should be using a list instead, e.g. `lsoup=[]` and `lsoup.append(bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')`

Comment: Also `for base_url in llista` instead of using range.

Comment: hi @MarkTolonen, i request to the url the HTML code to extract the class If__playerNameInner that containt the name of the players in the field, so when i review the code in the page, its a different code that i received in the requests on Python, thank you for help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the link you are referring has some dynamic elements. Browsers are using Javascript while rendering the website. So, when we request a HTML file from the website it gives us some sort of "non-rendered" HTML which is useless. If you disable javascript in Browser, you won't be able to open the link properly.

I had the same problem before, solution was using the Selenium. It didn't satisfied me, because it was overpowered solution for a simple problem. If someone knows a better solution, they can contribute my answer.

Here are some questions asked before about the SAME problem:

[HTML does not reflect webpage content in browser for Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495589/html-does-not-reflect-webpage-content-in-browser-for-beautiful-soup)

[Beautiful Soup not loading the entire page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213717/beautiful-soup-not-loading-the-entire-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)