# JavaScript on Site Prevents `requests.get` from Working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I’m trying to write a simple web-scraper, practicing on [this site](https://weighttraining.guide/exercises/standing-dumbbell-overhead-triceps-extension/) which has dynamic content.

My strategy is to use Selenium to get the page source so I have all the dynamic content, then scrape using Beautiful Soup. Basically, exactly the strategy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529849/python-scraping-javascript-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup)

I’m stuck on Step 1, however: I can’t get Selenium to even get the page. The following script gets through the ‘driver loaded’ print statement and then freezes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
    print("Driver loaded")
    driver.get("https://weighttraining.guide/exercises/standing-dumbbell-overhead-triceps-extension/")
    print("Selenium get successful")

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "entry-content"))
    )
    print("Page loaded")
    driver.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

When I run this script I see Chrome open the website and I can see it load successfully, but then the script freezes. I’ve tried this with and without any of the `chrome_options`, `user_agent`, and `WebDriverWait` portions. Nothing seems to work.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this by modifying the `headers` sent by the `requests.get` call, then using `Beautiful Soup` for the scraping. The point of Selenium is to get the JavaScript to load all the dynamic content so that then we have simple HTML to parse with `Beautiful Soup`, but for this site and many others Python's built-in `requests` library can mimic the browser enough to do this using `headers`. The performance is materially faster than `Selenium` too. Here's how it work:

```
headers = {
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1', 
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36', 
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 
    'sec-ch-ua': 'Google Chrome;v="84", "Chromium";v="84", ";Not A Brand";v="99"', 
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Windows', 
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none', 
    'sec-fetch-mod': '',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.5'
}

    response = requests.get(site, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

Note: use those headers in that order to look most like a real browser. Thank you [ScrapeOps](https://scrapeops.io/web-scraping-playbook/web-scraping-guide-header-user-agents/) for the headers.

Now we can use the `soup` object as expected:

```
in: soup.find('h1', {'class': 'entry-title'}).text
out: 'Standing dumbbell overhead triceps extension'
```

JavaScript defeated!